# C++ Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) wrapper

Tags: c++, windows, events, trace, etw

I have been investigating [Event Tracing for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/event-tracing-for-windows) (ETW) for use within existing backend/server applications.
MSDN and other sources have sold the power of the framework and its integration with [xperf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/), etc. which frankly I am impressed with.

However I am a bit concerned by the Win32 APIs and the overhead of working with the manifest coding  compilating/registration, etc.

Folks, do you:

- Recommend it? Have problems using it with your systems?
- Know of a more C++/STL style wrapper?
- Are there tools for managing the manifest files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using the Win32 API directly, I would recommend using WPP.

WPP is a pre-processor which allow you to write printf-like trace lines anywhere in your code and have the result of those, along with the additional data (e.g. the arguments passed to the various %d and %s in the trace) be logged to ETW.

The definite guide for this is *[WPP Tracing in Visual C++ 2010 Projects](https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-visual-studio/wpp-tracing-visual-c-2010-projects)*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Uri. Can I ask why you recommend WPP? It  avoids the xml manifest file I talked about.  I am a bit overwhelmed by the number of moving parts explained in the article you reference.  *.mof files, *.tmh files, tracepdb.exe. But I will check it out, it seems quite powerful.  Can one use xPerf to analyse these logs?

Comment: I haven't used XPerf but other SA thread say you use it for classic providers like WPP. I've implemented the solution myself and it has only boils down to adding a tracewpp pre-processor as pre-build event, including TMH files in your code, calling trace macros where appropriate, defining a single GUID and calling init/cleanup in the main. Additional Qs are welcome.

Comment: @UriCohen related to that article, how can you add multiple logging levels (err, warning) using WPP_CONTROL_GUIDS (I guess) ?

Comment: You can have multiple logging levels in the code. However, using WPP you write to 'classic ETW providers', which mean you can have only a single tracing session for it, with specific log level and flags which are set at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, ETW is very powerful. But at the same time, it's not that easy to start with it.

However, there is a project on GitHub that simplifies writing your own ETW provider. And it's a good example of writing:

- ETW manifest (.man) to disclose event fields
- WP**R** profile (.wprp) to teach WPRUI (recorder) about your profiler
- WP**A** profile (.wpaProfile) and regions of interest (.xml) to teach WPA about representation of your data.

Please look at the *[Intel single event API (SEAPI) wiki](https://github.com/01org/IntelSEAPI/wiki)*.