# ETW provider for WIN32 synchronization calls

Tags: winapi, etw

Which ETW provider can trace Win32 synchronization calls(
SetEvent, WaitForSingleObject, WaitForMultipleObjects, CreateEvent, ResetEvent )

Comment: Do you read [Consuming Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/consuming-events): Event trace consumers can process events from one or more providers. Consumers can process events from a log file or in real time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i don't  know from what provider i could get events for these calls,

Comment: It seems that WPP is what you need. The Windows software trace processor (WPP) provides an efficient mechanism to log events that occur during the execution of an application or driver. Similar case: [C++ Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400899/c-event-tracing-for-windows-etw-wrapper)

Comment: thank you again, but I would like to get these events without preliminary steps. Another words, i run some apps, collect  and see these events in trace( GPUView e.g.).

Comment: Bonus: [List of nifty ETW providers you didn't know existed](https://gist.github.com/mattifestation/04e8299d8bc97ef825affe733310f7bd)